# How do you play FIFA 12 online with the PC version?

Tags: fifa-12

I am new to online gaming and want to play the PC version of *FIFA 12* online.

What is the procedure for doing so?

Comment: What do you want to know exactly? Your question is far too broad and an answer could start with anything from "turn on your pc" to "click with your mouse on the button _play_".

Answer (score 0):

You need an original key and a stable connection.